# Prove that every horizontal line in the $x$-$y$ plane intersects the curve $y=x^5+3x^2$ at most $3$ times

Tags: calculus

How do you use the intermediate value theorem to prove that there are at least $3$ roots?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the derivative of $f(x)=x^5+3x^2-c$,
$$
f'(x)=5x^4+6x.
$$
This has exactly two real roots. By Rolle's theorem, $f(x)$ can have at most $3$ real roots.

By the intermediate value theorem, if $f(-1)=2-c$ is positive and $f(0)=-c$ is negative, $3$ real roots exist. If this condition $c\in(0,2)$ is violated too much (replace $-1$ by the root $-\sqrt[3]{6/5}$ of $f'$ for the exact condition) there will be only one real root.

Answer (score 0):

$$y=f(x)=x^5+3x^2 \implies y'=5x^4+6x=0 \implies x=0,- (6/5)^{1/3} \implies f''(0)=6>0, f''(-(6/5)^{1/3}) <0 \implies f_{min}=f(0)=0, f_{max}=f(-(6/5)^{1/3})=\frac{9}{5}\left(\frac{6}{5}\right)^{(2/3)}=y_0$$ So the line $y=k$ will cut the curbe $y=f(x)$ at three points if $0<k<y_0$, it will meet  this curve at two distinct points if $k=0,y_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the equation $$ y=x^5+3x^2-C$$ has only two critical points because $$y'= 5x^4+6x=0 \implies x(5x^3+6)=0$$

So the critical points are at $x=0$ and $x=-(6/5)^{(1/3)}$

With only two critical points the $S$ shaped polynomial can have at most three zeros which are the intersection of the horizontal line $y=C$ with our function.